# Error running gem5 Full System mode

Tags: arm, gem5

I got this error trying to run gem5 using Full System mode. I was following this guide: https://github.com/arm-university/arm-gem5-rsk/wiki

Any idea how to solve this or what is that `armv8_gem5_v1_1cpu.20170616.dtb`?

```
tomas@ubuntu:~/gem5$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu="minor" --num-cores=1 --disk-image=$M5_PATH/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled Jul  9 2018 19:01:20
gem5 started Jul 16 2018 11:04:01
gem5 executing on ubuntu, pid 2093
command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu=minor --num-cores=1 --disk-image=/home/tomas/arm-fs-gem5/aarch-system-20180409//disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tomas/gem5/src/python/m5/main.py", line 435, in main
    exec filecode in scope
  File "configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py", line 243, in <module>
    main()
  File "configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py", line 232, in main
    root.system = create(args)
  File "configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py", line 97, in create
    (args.num_cores, default_dist_version))
  File "/home/tomas/gem5/configs/common/SysPaths.py", line 67, in __call__
    raise IOError, "Can't find file '%s' on path." % filename
IOError: Can't find file 'armv8_gem5_v1_1cpu.20170616.dtb' on path.
```

Comment: It is a good idea to always the critical error message to the title, e.g. "Error running gem5 Full System mode: IOError: Can't find file '*.dtb' on path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly stating the kernel and dtb files solved the problem:

```
tomas@ubuntu:~/gem5$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu="minor" --num-cores=1 --disk-image=$M5_PATH/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --dtb=$M5_PATH/binaries/armv8_gem5_v1_1cpu.dtb --kernel=$M5_PATH/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled Jul  9 2018 19:01:20
gem5 started Jul 16 2018 11:41:55
gem5 executing on ubuntu, pid 2232
command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/arm/starter_fs.py --cpu=minor --num-cores=1 --disk-image=/home/tomas/arm-fs-gem5/aarch-system-20180409//disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --dtb=/home/tomas/arm-fs-gem5/aarch-system-20180409//binaries/armv8_gem5_v1_1cpu.dtb --kernel=/home/tomas/arm-fs-gem5/aarch-system-20180409//binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64

Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (2048 Mbytes)
info: kernel located at: /home/tomas/arm-fs-gem5/aarch-system-20180409//binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64
warn: Highest ARM exception-level set to AArch32 but bootloader is for AArch64. Assuming you wanted these to match.
system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900
system.terminal: Listening for connections on port 3456
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000
info: Using bootloader at address 0x10
info: Using kernel entry physical address at 0x80080000
info: Loading DTB file: /home/tomas/arm-fs-gem5/aarch-system-20180409//binaries/armv8_gem5_v1_1cpu.dtb at address 0x88000000
```

It seems that `starter_fs.py` is looking for some default files somewhere and it doesn't find them.

Comment: You should generally avoid explicitly using a DTB unless autogeneration isn't working. On fs.py, autogeneration is enabled if no --dtb option is given with an explicit DTB choice.